# how to avoid adding plugin each time a clone from git is done

Tags: cordova, npm, bower

I found out that in order to have my app working (and creating the correct apk) I have always to add manually the platform and each plugin for phonegap.

Is there a way to automate it?

Now I scaffolded the app with yo angular and I am using grunt to run each task and npm and bower for dependencies.

Actually I have to do this:

```
git clone http://address.git
npm install && bower install
```

and then also

```
cordova platform add android
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-camera cordova-plugin-file
```

is there a way to automate the last two inside the first two?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script that reads as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install && bower install
cordova platform add android
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-camera cordova-plugin-file
```

Place the script in your root directory in the git repo. Run the script every time you make a clone:

```
git clone http://address.git
address/setup.sh
```

Comment: I was wondering if can be a good idea to include a task in grunt such as "grunt init" using grunt-cordovacli